# jquery - Changing styling of a class containing a particular child class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want the height of `.pst` to be increased if it contains a child class `.pa` , the code below doesn't work, and if i use `'.pst'` instead of `this` keyword all the div elements with `.pst` changes. Help!

```
window.onload = function() {
if($('.pst').contents().find('.pa').length !=0){
    $(this).css('height','+=200px');
 }
}


<div class="pst">
 <div class="pa"></div>
 <div class="pa"></div>  
 <div class="pa"></div>  
 <div class="pa"></div>    
</div> 

<div class="pst">
 <div class="pb"></div>
 <div class="pb"></div>  
 <div class="pb"></div>  
 <div class="pb"></div>    
</div>
```

Comment: What about `$('.pst').find('.pa').length` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the **height of .pst to be increased** if it contains a child class .pa

You are using $(this) in if condition which refers to the global window object not to the current `.pst` element.

Consider using [each](http://api.jquery.com/each):

```
$('.pst').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('.pa').length){
    $(this).css('height','+=200px');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! by adding .contents() before .find('.pa') the code worked

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it with [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has/) selector:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('.pst:has(.pa)').css('height', '+=200px');
}
```

Above will select and increase height of only those `.pst` which have `.pa` descendants.

Answer (score 1):

No need to check contents, just target the class combination you want using `$('.pst .pa')`. Then you can loop the items using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Here's a runnable snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.pst .pa').each(function() {
    $(this).css('height','+=200px');
 });
});
```

```css
.pa {background-color: blue; margin: 5px; height:50px; width:50px; float:left}
.pb {background-color: blue; margin: 5px; height:50px; width:50px; float:left}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pst">
 <div class="pa"></div>
 <div class="pa"></div>  
 <div class="pa"></div>  
 <div class="pa"></div>    
</div> 

<div class="pst">
 <div class="pb"></div>
 <div class="pb"></div>  
 <div class="pb"></div>  
 <div class="pb"></div>    
</div>
```